# dict from dataclass returns empty dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-dataclasses

I'm new to dataclasses and am trying to make a simple way to convert one to a dictionary with I can then save and load from a JSON file. Before I implement the infrastructure I need for my application, I'm testing it on a small dataclass with the variables I'll be working with which is below:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
@dataclass 
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, floatA:[float], intA:[int], floatB:[float]):
        self.var1 = floatA
        self.var2 = intA
        self.var3 = floatB

    def ConvertToDict(self):
        return asdict(self)

test = TestClass([0.2,0.1,0.5], [1,2,3], [0.9,0.7,0.6])
print(asdict(test))
print(test.ConvertToDict())
```

Both print statements are an empty dictionary '{}' and I can't seem to figure out why

Comment: You didn't annotate anything and implemented your own init..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By overriding the `__init__` method you are effectively making the `dataclass` decorator a no-op. I think you want:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
@dataclass 
class TestClass:
    floatA: float
    intA: int
    floatB: float

    def asdict(self):
        return asdict(self)

test = TestClass([0.2,0.1,0.5], [1,2,3], [0.9,0.7,0.6])
print(test)
print(test.asdict())
```

Which produces as output:

```
TestClass(floatA=[0.2, 0.1, 0.5], intA=[1, 2, 3], floatB=[0.9, 0.7, 0.6])
{'floatA': [0.2, 0.1, 0.5], 'intA': [1, 2, 3], 'floatB': [0.9, 0.7, 0.6]}
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you. I missed that part of the documentation for some reason

Comment: You can add your own __init__ method, but you still need to declare the dataclass fields as class variables for them to be recognized. Example: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#custom-init-method

Comment: Does it still work in recent python versions (like 3.10)? I am getting empty dict.

Comment: The code in this answer does not produce an empty `dict` when run under Python 3.10. If I copy and paste the code into a file `testcode.py` and run `python testcode.py` using `Python 3.10.4`, it produces the output shown in the answer.